# How to recreate square waves over wireless in 'real time'

Tags: wireless

I currently work with a product that is designed to capture data from three simple digital sensors and perform some calculations based on the outputs.

The sensors produce square waves (with different mark-space ratios) with frequencies from 1Hz to 100KHz.

The first iteration of the product was easy, it was wired, so was a simple matter of feeding the signals to a micro-controller and triggering interrupts.

The second iteration was a wireless solution where each signal had its frequency averaged over a short period, then sent via an XBee module, before finally reconstituting the averaged frequency at the other end.
This solution works OK when the signal frequencies don't change, but understandably has accuracy issues when they do.

So my question is; how can I recreate my three digital signals over wireless as close to real time as possible?

I have a couple of initial thoughts of things that 'might' work, but some more expert knowledge/guidance would be appreciated.

1. Sending some sort of time synchronisation message, and transmitting only time stamp data at a high data rate.
2. Using a low precision (4-bit?), high speed ADC to capture the signal, and then streaming the data continuously over wireless, and then using a DAC to convert this back to a signal again at the other end.

[image]

Comment: To clarify your case: You develop a data capture device, which samples 3 channels. You want to feed test data into that device via a wireless XBee bridge?
Edit: Your sensors capture only digital Signals?

Comment: @DennisErnst That is a good summary, although the bridge doesn't necessarily have to be XBee, we are willing to consider any wireless technology

Comment: Okay some more questions:
- How is the test-data on the other end of the XBee generated?
- Whats the purpose of the wireless bridge? (just galavanic isolation?)
- As I'm not sure: The capture device reads only digital data?

Comment: @DennisErnst Currently the averaged frequency is sent as a frequency, and then that frequency is recreated by a microcontroller at the other end.  It is certainly a less than ideal solution.  Yes, the signals are digital only.  The purpose of the wireless solution is to allow the user freedom of movement without trailing 10+m cables to/from a handheld device.

Comment: Either analyze the signal at the source and transmit a digital packet of conclusions.  Or get something of sufficient bandwidth (maybe an FM video link?) send it raw and hope for the best, which will likely include interference failures at times.

Comment: Ok I still dont get it. Will the capture device be wireless or just your test-setup?
Edit: Please just make a graphic for clarification

Comment: The key step that seems to be missing here is that you need to decide what information you need, how often, and what sort of radio failure/corruption strategy would be suitable.   If you can reduce the need to something simple, the solution is simple.  If you need a perfect reconstruction the solution may range from difficult to impossible.

Comment: @DennisErnst I've added a block diagram (click to zoom in) of the 'system' that is composed of 3 remote sensor devices and a handheld analysis device.

Comment: Do you just need to know the instantaneous frequency, or do you need to know the relative sequence of edges between the sensors? For example, is it enough to know that A and B are both 1KHz or do you need to know 1KHz and A is 60 degrees leading B? And how often do you need to know?

Comment: @user1850479 We need to know how the edges relate to each other.  In an ideal world i'd like to know this every 1ms (i don't know if that is feasible).

Comment: That is harder then. In this case I would get FM transmitters, bandpass filter to cos, and then transmit analog.  With a strong carrier and short distances you shouldn't have much trouble with errors. Maybe take a look at FM lapel mics or similar audio FM solution. You want to solve essentially the same problem as a PA system in a large building (make multiple speakers audible to everyone without delay).

Comment: Unless or until you can simplify or have a fairly high tolerance for error/dropout,  I suggest you not pursue this - you will likely find that you spend a lot of money on gear, a lot of time, and don't end up with something actually usable.

Answer (score 2):

user1850479's suggestion seems the most workable. Filter the square waves down to sine waves, but with the zero crossings in the same place. Then you can either broadcast them on a shortrange audio solution if you can find one that works at up to 100kHZ - *not* bluetooth, since that subjects you to compression and latency. Or you can build your own small FM transmitter in a suitable band.

Have a look at the [EU radio bands allocation](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32013D0752&from=EN); you'll end up picking 434.04-434.79MHz or 863-865MHz at low power, given that you'll be using 100% duty cycle for continuous transmission.

At the receiver end, use a comparator with hysterisis to reconstruct the square waves and identify the zero crossings. Or you can do it in an ADC if you prefer.